# Most of the pages show "insecure connection" in Opera

Tags: security, opera-browser

I have changed some security settings in my Android yesterday (I don't remember which one). Today most of the pages show "insecure connection" in Opera. I cannot even go to youtubel.com

Everything opens as normal in Firefox.

I've reinstalled Opera, but the problem remains.

How can I undo this?

Comment: If Firefox works and Opera shows errors then the date of the device seems to be correct. May be you have changed the DNS configuration?

Comment: Would it be in Opera settings or in the phone settings? Does not seem like an Opera setting (I've reinstalled Opera, but the problem remains). How to check it?

Comment: You wrote in your first line that you changed Android settings so guess what settings could be changed...

Comment: You must have disabled "Trusted credentials" in Security settings. Firefox works because it doesn't use Android's SSL certificates but has its own database. All apps relying on Android's CA database for HTTPS connections will stop working.

Comment: @IrfanLatif Make your comment an answer, so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fiddled with the problem for a couple of days.

My working solution was to backup my files, reset to factory defaults, reinstall apps (took 1-2 hours).

---

Update: @Irfan Latif is correct. These were indeed the security -> trusted credentials. That comment should have being the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the reason re-installing Opera didn't fix it is because your probably still using the same profile.  Let me put it this way, when you re-installed you still had all your bookmarks still without having to import them again... ergo same profile.

Did you try going into Settings, Advanced and then click on Reset Settings (which restore settings to their original defaults)?

If you don't have that option or that doesn't work for you, do a backup of your bookmarks, et cetera and then create a new profile. Try entering opera:about in the url bar and then see if it tells you where your profile is located, close Opera, navigate to that location and delete everything.  Upon re-opening Opera it should create a new profile.

I assume this is regular Opera and not Opera GX, you may want to have a look at [this](https://blogs.opera.com/desktop/2022/03/opera-gx-gx-profiles-video-pickup/) if switching between profiles sounds good to you.